# Using archlinux on vmware error 8000

Tags: linux, arch-linux, vmware

I have been playing around with Linux a bit and I wanted to try using [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/) so I downlaoded the `.iso` and I set up vmware player saying that it was another Linux 2.6x kernel. As soon as I launched it, I got this error `EDD: Error 8000 reading sector 269058` does anyone know what is wrong and how I can fix this?

**My System Info:**

- OS:Windows 7 Home Premium<
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410m CPU @ 2.30GHz 2.30 GHz
- System Type: 64-bit Operating System
- Virtualization: Enabled

Comment: This looks like a corrupted ISO. Can you try redownloading it?

Comment: Try getting the md5sum of this iso file and verify it on your copy of it. If they are not the same, your copy of the iso is corrupt

Comment: Also have a look through [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error+8000+reading+sector).

Comment: @mauro.stettler when you look at the [download page](http://mirrors.aggregate.org/archlinux/iso/2013.08.01/) it shows a couple of options, however I do not know which one to download. Any ideas of which one?

Comment: not sure about vmware player - but i can confirm arch runs with zero issues on Virtualbox (and I happen to think virtualbox is a better type-2 hypervisor to run on your desktop)

Comment: If the host machine is Linux, you probably want to take a look at KVM. Virt-manager is super sexy and KVM run stuff better on bare metal for me than VMWares ESXi on the same hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said above in the comments the file was corrupt(after talking with OP we confirmed that) and I sent him a link to a no corrupt download,